# Jquery UI Resizable() resize div from right side of browser window not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to create two slideout pannels on the left and right side of the browser window. I also want the panels to be resizable horizontaly from left to right and from right to left.

I have [created example code](http://jsfiddle.net/USRFobiwan/sGHtG/6/) you can see and try out. You can resize the left panel without any problem, but the right panel show some erratic behaviors.

Does somebody have a better idea or another way to resize the div on the right side of the window?

---

In the end I found a awesome plugin that can handle all kind of panels. Its called ui layout and if anyone is interested, you can find it here:

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Answer (score 0):

Why not call resizable on #right_slide_panel instead of .panel_content ?

Comment: even if we do that the right panel still doesn't resize like the left panel